# Xamarin: Can't Load Styles.xml

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I tried creating a Styles.xml in my values resource directory, but it turns out anytime I try to build the file it fails. I can't seem to figure out the problem. Is it some kind of bug in Xamarin or am I doing something wrong? PS: I am very new to Xamarin.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

And I get the error below:

```
Resources/values/Styles.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

 0 Warning(s)
 1 Error(s)
```

Comment: What is your android project build target?

Comment: Check if the styles are updating on Resources.designer.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that no item found `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

This means that you don't have the `AppCompat` installed.

Add the [Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/) nuget to your android project.

Comment: I did, still will not build

Comment: Sorry for the late response, it is a different kind of the same error :)  `No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:colorAccent' with value '@color/colorAccent').`

Comment: You have do declare the @color/colorAccent in colors.xml.

Comment: I did, I have all the above colors listed there

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to reproduce your issue, using the following sample that I created. Here is my Styles.xml, which is located under Resources/values:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

and here is my Colors.xml located also under Resources/values

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="colorPrimary" type="color">#FF33B5E5</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark" type="color">#FFAA66CC</item>
    <item name="colorAccent" type="color">#FF99CC00</item>
</resources>
```

and the app builds without issue.

If you are still having issues, I would need to see either a copy of your app, or the full content of the styles.xml and colors.xml

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some searching i found out that you should delete the whole content in your: (Make a copy of the content before deleting and close Visual Studio)

**"C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Xamarin.Android"**

and

**"C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Xamarin"**

Folders

Clean Solution -> Rebuild Solution => worked for me

Source: https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/268d81f